# New method created from class can't be accessed in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods

ItemAdd says "does not contain definition". I cant access the method I created, but other methods i created earlier can be accessed. I really don't know what is going on in here. I already tried to Rebuild my solution, and restart my VS.

```
using ClassLibrary1;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

DataAccess da = new DataAccess();


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void AddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string itm, stck;
    float prce;

    itm = itemname.Text.ToString();
    stck = stocks.Text.ToString();
    prce = float.Parse(price.Text.ToString());

    da.ItemAdd(itm, stck, prce); //<- ITEM ADD IS UNDERLINED BY RED
}
}
```

And here is my Class DataAccess

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
public class DataAccess
{

    private static SqlConnection conn = SetUpConnection.ConString();

    public void ItemAdd(string itemname, string stocks, float price)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddItem", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ItemName", itemname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Stocks", stocks);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Price", price);


        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

    }


}
}
```

[This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmwVp.png)

[Other methods created previously can be accessed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx0a7.png)

Comment: At which line inside ItemAdd method exception appear?

Comment: Try to add full error message details

Comment: There are no errors. Its just VS can't find the method ItemAdd. So when i hover the mouse to "da.ItemAdd" it says "does not contain a definition for '' and no extension method "

Comment: `static SqlConnection conn` <= do not do that. Create connections on an as needed basis and wrap them in a `using` block. If you do this in an asp.net app you will get race conditions, ie: bugs. Only one use will ever be able to use the DB at a time.

Comment: As for your error it is probably how you are referencing your 2 projects. Make sure that the asp.net app *references the project* and not the compiled dll on disk somewhere. Also make sure there are no build errors for the project that keep a new version being generated.

Comment: Does the program compile and build successfully? Did you try restarting VS?

Comment: I tried restarting it many times. No errors. Only cant find the method

Comment: So apparently I have no choice but to create a new website and copy all the codes, then it works :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1) If you are using it in different namespace and trying to use the other namespace's dll then it wont refer this method.

3) You may need to rebuild the project

I think second option might be the cause for you. Please post more information in order to understand exact problem of yours.

Comment: I already did try rebuilding it. No statements error in "ItemAdd" method, but VS cant find it. Other methods from the same class can be used. I dont know why this "ItemAdd" cant. ItemAdd was the latest method i created. It happens so on and so on if i create new methods

Comment: could you please remove static in "static SqlConnection conn"  and try?

Comment: Nothing happens.